# Deploying a portable PyInstaller exe file

Tags: python, certificate, pyinstaller, sign

So I have just created a simple, standalone exe file from PyInstaller. I sent it to a friend to try to use, but apparently it won't run, even on admin. After a bit of searching, I found out that as I haven't signed the file, other people can't run it. I've been digging around the Internet on how to make a certificate and sign it to an exe, but no luck. Can anybody help me STEP BY STEP?
Note that this exe is standalone (portable).

Comment: what's the error information when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to buy a certificate that Windows trusts, e.g. from https://www.ksoftware.net/code-signing-certificates/

Don't bother with self-signed certificates. Not worth your time.